# Python Django slug url error

Tags: python, django

I am writing a practice python django website. I am trying to connect the links, slugs, in my contact.html to separate html pages. Imputing the URL by hand for these objects outputs the site correctly. However, the links in contact.html won't like to the pages.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% block content %}
    <body>
        <h1>Contact page</h1>
            <div class = "contact">
            {% for contact in contact %}
                <h2><a href="{ % url 'detail' slug = contact.slug %}">{{contact.title}}</a></h2>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
    </body>
    {% endblock %}
```

contact_detail.html (the page href in contact.html should like to this html; both html files are in contact/contact/templates)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% block content %}
    <body>
            <div class = "contact">
            <p>{{contact.title}}</p>
            <p>{{contact.body}}</p>
            </div>
    </body>
    {% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Contact
from django.http import HttpResponse
def contact(request):
    contact = Contact.objects.all() 
    return render(request, 'contact/templates/contact.html', {'contact': contact})
def contact_details(request, slug):
    contacts = Contact.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'contact/templates/contact_detail.html', {'contact': contacts})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url('^$', views.contact, name="list"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.contact_details, name = "detail"),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Contact
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Contact)
```

error

```
Using the URLconf defined in katiesite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^contact/ ^$ [name='list']
^contact/ ^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$ [name='detail']
^$
The current path, contact/{ % url 'detail' slug = contact1.slug %}, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space after the opening bracket of your URL tag, so it is not getting parsed. Remove the space.

```
 "{ % url 'detail' slug = contact.slug %}"
#  ^ here
```

Comment: I tried that but it still returns an error. It states (current path contact/{ % url). It seems to not be registering the change. I made sure to save the url and even migrate the server